# In vs code my speech_recognition doesn't working and showing pyaudio not found error

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, voice-recognition, pyaudio

```
raise AttributeError("Could not find PyAudio; check installation")
```

AttributeError: Could not find PyAudio; check installation

Comment: do you .. have it installed?

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stackoverflow! Could you share your code?